# Is it possible to define a projective line that intersects a projective cubic only once?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, tangent-line

I have been working on this and by Bezout I believe that if the line is to intersect a cubic in only one point it must do so with multiplicity 3. I am though unsure given a point $P$ on a cubic how I may define a line also incident with this point but not incident with the cubic again

Comment: Suggestion: If you don't have intuition for this, consider in the affine plane what are the conditions for a line to have a triple intersection with a cubic. Then relate that to the projective space you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the projective line comes inside intersecting at one point and leaving through the same point